# Page Numbering in Letter Environment has no desired effect with \usepackage{scrletter}

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, multiple-files

For a long application I have got the following problem: I cannot seem to make page numbering in the letter working.

My workflow is the following: I have got a main document with all preamble-information and

```
{scrartcl}
```

as documentclass; in the preamble I load

```
\usepackage{scrletter}
```

to have access to letter features of the koma-script letter features; the main document is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,%
fontsize=12pt,parskip=half*,%
headings=optiontoheadandtoc,%
headlines=5,headinclude=on,version=last]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[dvips,final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt} % Spacing around sections


\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\clearscrheadfoot

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{
\normalfont\small
}

\ohead{\textsc{Application}\\ \normalfont{Some Summer School}}

\ihead{ \\E.G. \textsc{Smith}}

\cfoot*{\thepage}

\areaset{155mm}{264mm}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcaptionname{english}{\subjectname}{%
Application}
}

\renewcommand\raggedsignature{\raggedright}

\begin{document}

\include{title}

\tableofcontents

\include{letter}

\include{cv}

\includepdf[pages=-, scale=0.88,addtotoc={1,section,1,Some Summer School 2017: Online Registration,sosusconline}, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{scrheadings}}]{transcripts/abc.pdf}

\includepdf[pages=1-2, frame, scale=0.88,addtotoc={1,section,1,Transcript Grades: Some University,trgsou}, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{scrheadings}}]{transcripts/def.pdf}
.
.
.

\includepdf[pages=-, frame, scale=0.88,addtotoc={1,section,1,Copy of Passport, passport}, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{scrheadings}}]{transcripts/reisepass-print.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Then there are

```
title.tex, cv.tex, and letter.tex
```

Letter.tex looks like this:

```
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosed}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{subject}{Application}

\let\letterpagemark\pagemark

\begin{letter}[]{University\\
Office of International Relations\\
Some Summer School 2017''\\
}

\pagestyle{letter}

\LoadLetterOption{annam-en}

\opening{Dear Sir/ Madam,}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Application Letter}

blablablablabla blala blabla

\closing{Yours sincerely,}

\encl{Resume, Letter of Recommendation, Transcripts, Certificates, Print Copy of Online Registration form, blablabla}

\end{letter}
```

Even though page numbering works out of the box, even with the pdf-pages, I can not set the page number of the letter to 3. The page number is always set to 1 on the first letter. I tried to put

```
\setcounter{page}{3}
```

after

```
\opening
```

to no effect.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the `page` counter before the letter, and then restore it with `\AtBeginLetter` because KOMA-Script otherwise resets it when the letter starts. If you want the page number to print on the first page of the letter, you also need to provide a suitable `\thispagestyle{}` **after** the opening of the letter, because KOMA-Script at that point sets it to `empty`.

(Note that as esdd points out in a comment to the question, you could just set the value by hand -- but saving and restoring allow for changes in the earlier parts of the document.)

MWE follows. Note that there was a lot in your posted code that was unnecessary to the problem.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\clearpage

\newcounter{pagesaver}%to save the value
\setcounter{pagesaver}{\value{page}}%set it to the current value of page
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosed}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{subject}{Application}
\AtBeginLetter{\setcounter{page}{\value{pagesaver}}}%restore value at start of letter

\begin{letter}[]{University\\
Office of International Relations\\
Some Summer School 2017\\
}

\opening{Dear Sir/ Madam,}

\thispagestyle{letter}

\Blindtext

\closing{Yours sincerely,}

\encl{Resume, Letter of Recommendation, Transcripts, Certificates, Print Copy of Online Registration form, blablabla}

\end{letter}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```